Uncompressed dicom with cornerstone3D can render mpr images using volume, which cannot be rendered after compression
Compression mode（JPEG Extended (Process 2 & 4): Default
Transfer Syntax for Lossy JPEG 12 Bit Image
Compression (Process 4 only)
1.2.840.10008.1.2.4.51）
The 1.23.0 version of the library rendered normally, but I was unable to load compressed images after upgrading to 1.85.0.
I render the image in volume mode, I don't know what went wrong`
async function loadDcm () {
    await initcornerstone();
    try {
        hideLoadingContainer();
        let dcm1_container = document.getElementById('dcm1');
        let dcm2_container = document.getElementById('dcm2');
        let dcm3_container = document.getElementById('dcm3');
        element1 = document.createElement('div');
        element2 = document.createElement('div');
        element3 = document.createElement('div');
        element1.style.width = elemet1Style.width;
        element1.style.height = elemet1Style.height;
        element2.style.width = elemet2Style.width;
        element2.style.height = elemet2Style.height;
        element3.style.width = elemet3Style.width;
        element3.style.height = elemet3Style.height;
        element1.oncontextmenu = (e) => e.preventDefault();
        element2.oncontextmenu = (e) => e.preventDefault();
        element3.oncontextmenu = (e) => e.preventDefault();
        dcm1_container.appendChild(element1);
        dcm2_container.appendChild(element2);
        dcm3_container.appendChild(element3);
        renderingEngine = new RenderingEngine(renderingEngineId);
        volume = await volumeLoader.createAndCacheVolume(volumeId, {
            imageIds: imageIds.value,
        });
       
        const viewportInputArray = [
            {
                viewportId: viewportId1.value,
                element: element1,
                type: ViewportType.ORTHOGRAPHIC,
                defaultOptions: {
                    orientation: viewport_orientation[0],
                },
            },
            {
                viewportId: viewportId2.value,
                element: element2,
                type: ViewportType.ORTHOGRAPHIC,
                defaultOptions: {
                    orientation: viewport_orientation[1],
                },
            },
            {
                viewportId: viewportId3.value,
                element: element3,
                type: ViewportType.ORTHOGRAPHIC,
                defaultOptions: {
                    orientation: viewport_orientation[2],
                },
            },
        ];
        renderingEngine.setViewports(viewportInputArray);
        let viewport1 = renderingEngine.getVolumeViewports()[0];
        await volume.load();
        await setVolumesForViewports(
            renderingEngine,
            [{ volumeId }],
            viewportIds
        )
        renderingEngine.renderViewports(viewportIds);
    } catch (error) {
        hideLoadingContainer();
        console.error(error);
        cancelLoading();
    }
}


import dicomParser from 'dicom-parser';
import * as cornerstone from '@cornerstonejs/core';
import * as cornerstoneTools from '@cornerstonejs/tools';
import cornerstoneDICOMImageLoader from '@cornerstonejs/dicom-image-loader';
window.cornerstone = cornerstone;
window.cornerstone3DTools = cornerstoneTools;
const { preferSizeOverAccuracy, useNorm16Texture } = cornerstone.getConfiguration().rendering;
export default function initCornerstoneDICOMImageLoader() {
  cornerstoneDICOMImageLoader.external.cornerstone = cornerstone;
  cornerstoneDICOMImageLoader.external.dicomParser = dicomParser;
  cornerstoneDICOMImageLoader.configure({
    useWebWorkers: true,
    decodeConfig: {
      convertFloatPixelDataToInt: false,
      use16BitDataType: preferSizeOverAccuracy || useNorm16Texture,
    },
  });
  let maxWebWorkers = 1;
  if (navigator.hardwareConcurrency) {
    maxWebWorkers = Math.min(navigator.hardwareConcurrency, 7);
  }
  var config = {
    maxWebWorkers,
    startWebWorkersOnDemand: false,
    taskConfiguration: {
      decodeTask: {
        initializeCodecsOnStartup: false, 
        strict: false, 
      },
    },
  };
  cornerstoneDICOMImageLoader.webWorkerManager.initialize(config);
}

